# Predictable Linear Congruence or Pseudorandom Number Generator

Tags: algorithm, random

I am trying to identify the mathematical algorithm of something like a linear congruence or pseudo-random number generator that result in periodically predictable values.

About ten years ago I worked with a similar algorithm that was predictable based on the date and current time and produced a key that was used to change an internal password to a system.

On the outside we implemented the same algorithm, resulting in enabling us to access the system even though the password changed, and we otherwise did not know or have communicated to us what the password was.

I don't recall or have access to the algorithm any more.

Does anybody have an idea on how to implement this, or what I should search for to come up with an algorithm that could meet my needs?

EDIT:
Adding more specific requirements.

1. This can be a new algorithm.
2. This should generate a unique value during when called, if a given time period has passed. For example, it should return the same value during the hour of 1:00 am.
3. This should return the same value during a given time period, no matter on what machine or system it is executed. For example on computer A it should generate 1234, and on computer B it should also generate 1234, without communicating with each other, during the hour of 1:00 am.

Comment: Well, the [linear congruential generator (LCG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is a well-known (and easy to break I might add) PRNG. But that algorithm is formulated in terms of on an integer, the juicy bits are how date and time are fed to it and how exactly it's used to generate the passwords. Are you trying to find the exact algorithm used back then, or do you have a problem to solve that you think should be approached similarly? In the latter case, put up some actual requirements!

Comment: Are you looking for information on how to [Crack random number generators](https://jazzy.id.au/default/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html)?

Comment: I'm not trying to crack anything, and I don't necessarily need that exact algorithm - I'm trying to build a new one - I want a number generator that generates unique values that are predictable, in that the generator running on one system will generate the same value as the generator running on another system during the same hour. The next hour they will again generate the same value, but it would be unique compared to the previous value (or it could be every minute - different resolutions can be considered).

Comment: I don't get it - if you initialize any PRNG with the same seed, you get exactly the same "random" sequence - so they are predictable. What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: Seeding a PRNG, taking a small fixed number of outputs from it, then throwing away its state is just a very poor man's hash function of the seed. Also, why is *unique* a requirement? I don't even think this is mathematically possible without communication, save for very predictable values more or less immediately based on the time. A pseudo random value with negligible chance of collision, on the other hand...